# Get intersection of sets in mysql db

Tags: mysql, sql, intersection

I have next example table:

```
+===========================+
| person_id | preference_id |
+===========+===============+
|     1     |       1       |
|     1     |       2       |
|     1     |       3       |
|     2     |       1       |
|     3     |       4       |
|     4     |       1       |
|     4     |       3       |
|     5     |       2       |
|     5     |       8       |
+___________+_______________+
```

And I want to get first 10 intersection of sets for person_id 1 (yes, example include only 5 persons). 
I mean:
    (1,2,3) ∩ (1) ∩ (4) ∩ (1,3) ∩ (2,8)

We have three intersections for 'person_id 1' of four sets
    for person_id 2: (1)
    for person_id 4: (1,3)
    for person_id 5: (2)

```
//person_id 3: no set that contains in person_id 1
```

And… we do not know about person_id 2,3,4,5 etc. person_id and preference_id include over 10000 rows.
As you seen I want:
- fast clean way for search intersections in mysql
- get top 10 intersections (person_id 4 most relevant on the assumption of number of positions. Then 2 and 5)
Thank you for attention.

Comment: . . I, for one, have no idea what you are asking.  Take a deep breath, a sip of water.  Edit the question, and pretend that you are explaining it to a child.  We don't have the context of the problem you are trying to solve.  What do the columns mean?  What is the purpose of your request?  What are the results you are expecting?  And do you realize that for your initial request, the answer is the empty set?

Comment: I think I understand what he wants: the person_id that has the most preference_id's in common with person_id 1.

Comment: Actually, he wants the top 10 person_ids, ranked by the number of preference_ids they have in common with person_id. Think dating service trying to match people by the number of common interests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT t2.person_id, COUNT(*) int_size, GROUP_CONCAT(t2.preference_id) shared_preferences
FROM table t1
JOIN table t2 ON t1.preference_id = t2.preference_id
WHERE t1.person_id = 1
AND t2.person_id != 1
GROUP BY t2.person_id
ORDER BY int_size DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Barmar, thank you for this. You understand me correctly (but it is not dating service). Sorry - I cant vote up.

Comment: I meant it's _like_ the algorithm in a dating service.

Comment: Yes, It is my mistake (english is not native).